# setState before returning any value

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

So, I have a property in the state of a component called "method" which is set to an empty string (""), and a function called selectMethod ==>

```
  selectMethod = (e) => {
      const x = e.target.getAttribute("return-data");  
      this.setState({method: x});  
      console.log(this.state.method);
  }
```

which is fired when I click a button

```
<button onClick={this.selectMethod} return-data="test">SELECT</button>
```

What I expected to be shown in the console is "test". but when I clicked the button just the empty string is shown and then when I click on the button one more time the "test" word is shown. 
What I'm trying to do is to make the property method set to "test" before is gets consoled and make test show up on the console from the first click. I don't know why it's doing this. I mean "method" should be set to "test" before it gets consoled.

Comment: As you can see from @RoseRobertson's answer you can use a callback in the `setState` method. But, there is a more simple way, at least for me :) Log your state in the `render` method.

Comment: I'm still a beginner with React so I'm not sure if I get what you mean. Can you please provide me with an example?

Comment: just `console.log(x)` here - `console.log(this.state.method)` makes sense in `render` which is forced by state change

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setState` doesn't happen immediately, so you can't rely on it being the new value in the same run loop like that. However, it does take a callback as its second argument that you can use if necessary. Found a short little medium post about this for ya - https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296

Example:

`this.setState({method: x}, function () { console.log(this.state.method); })`

Comment: Though this question is a duplicate of many previous ones since you provided an answer I think it would be better providing an example code instead of a link here :)

Comment: @devserkan Thanks, I've added an example :)  I am admittedly bad at stackoverflow duplicate answer etiquette, this is not my first offense (although maybe the first time I've been called out for it )

Comment: Lol, no problem. We see lots of questions about that, this is why I know there are so many duplicates. Generally, we initiate a `close` vote request here but since there is an answer I suggested a code example. Also, OP requested another answer then I've provided one. So, I am a guilty, too :) Also, upvoted for the update.

Answer (score 3):

As explained since `setState` is asynchronous your immediate `console.log` call can't catch up the update. You have two options here:

1. Using `setState` method's callback.
2. Logging your state in your `render` method.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    name: ""
  };

  updateName = () =>
    this.setState({ name: "foo" }, () => console.log(this.state.name));

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.name);
    return <button onClick={this.updateName}>Update name</button>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

As you can see we are logging in two places here. One with the callback, one in `render` method. Since there isn't any name in the first render, you see `""` here at first. After the state is updated you see the value.

Comment: I think the callback method makes more sense. What I'm trying to do here is to make "foo" show up just one time after the first click. I don't need the empty string to be returned at all, right?

Comment: If your intent is just logging it, then there is no difference. The empty string is just coming from the first render. There is no harm or no benefit from seeing it.

Comment: Also, I like logging the state in the `render` method, so I can see how the related state property or state at all changes. The new one comes after the old one, a kind of comparison, just for logging purposes of course.